# Creating an edit method using a singly linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, edit

Is there any way I can edit a specific node's data within a linked list? I started writing a method:

```
public void edit(int index, String data) {

Node pre = head;
Node temp = null;
for(int i=1; i <= index; i++) {
  temp = pre;
  pre = pre.next();
}

temp.next(new Node(data));
pre.data(data);
}
```

I have four nodes in my list, I used this method to edit the node at index 1 in the list, however now when I print out all elements in the list it only shows nodes at index 0 and 1, and 2-3 do not appear. Any hints on whats going wrong here?

Comment: Consider that when you edit an element not at the end you have to append the remaining nodes to the new node. You should also not iterate based on the index unless you've already verified it's < the list size.

Comment: You also don't need the temp nor the new node; you can just set data to the new value.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void edit(int index, String data) {

     Node pre = head;
     Node temp = null;
     for(int i=1; i <= index; i++) {
        temp = pre;
        pre = pre.next();
     }

     Node newNote = new Node(data);
     temp.next = newNote;
     newNote.next = pre.next;
}
```

You should also handle the some specific situations. For example: This code doesn't work for index = 0. And This code throws exceptions for linked list size when be 0. And This code also throws exceptions when index bigger then linked list size. And things like that

Answer (score 0):

```
public void edit(int index, String data) {

 if (index==0) {
  head.data(data);
  return;
 }

 if (index < 0 || index > size()) {
   throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index out of bounds.");
  }

 Node pre = head;
 Node temp = null;
 for(int i=1; i <= index; i++) {
    temp = pre;
    pre = pre.next;
 }

 Node newNode = new Node(data);
 temp.next(newNode);
 newNode.next(pre.next);
}
```

@Mustafa Akıllı Something like this?